# How many arXiv papers are uploaded in their final (refereed) versions?

Tags: publications, arxiv

In a [recent meta.physics.se discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4820/8563) on the use of permanent links form physics.stackexchange, I proposed as policy that

> when linking to the arXiv, link to the abstract page (arxiv.org/abs/...) and not directly to the pdf, as a courtesy to users on lower bandwidths. If the paper has been published (which will be noted on the arXiv abstract), *include a link to the journal version, even if it's paywalled, if only as a courtesy to the referees' hard work.*

One comment on the italicized part was

> Doesn't pretty much everybody post the final version on arxiv?

and I would like to know (if that is even possible) to what extent this is true. My gut feeling is that this is field-dependent, but I do not know what evidence may be available to explore this, other than anecdotal evidence.

Thus: **Is there a clear trend for authors to upload post-referee-process versions after publication?** Does this depend on the specific field? What evidence is available for this?

Comment: Until recently, I thought that posting to arXiv the post-refereed version was considered bad form, especially if the author has already transferred copyright to the journal.  However, I recently discovered that this is *allowed* by many publishers, including Elsevier.  [You can check on what is allowed by specific publishers](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?id=30&fIDnum=|&mode=simple&la=en).

Comment: @DanC Thank you for the link. I know that publisher policies on what is allowed vary, but for now I'm mostly interested in whether people actually take advantage of those rights or not, or in which fields they do.

Comment: In math (specifically math.CO), I rarely (maybe 1 out of 20 or rarer) see comments stating that the paper is post-refereed.  I think the Elsevier policy on posting post-refereed versions is probably fairly new, in light of the Elsevier boycott.  As a result, I think more people may take advantage of it as they become aware.  For the time being, I believe it is uncommon.

Comment: @DanC: I believe also Springer recently changed their policy in that direction. See also http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/11226/725 about increasing rights for authors.

Comment: @DanC: What do you mean by comments stating that the paper is post-refereed?  Do you mean something explicit like "This is the final, published version"?  It has never occurred to me to add a comment like that, although I always update papers post-refereeing.  I'd guess that a lot of people do this without explicit comment.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician The arXiv submission process has  a Comments field.  When I submit a revision, I use that field to describe the changes from the previous version.  I suspected that was standard, but perhaps it is not.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: moreover, it has a "journal-ref" field, where you can give the final citation. I'm frequently wondering whether arXiv (or other author archived manuscripts) are the final version, and of what paper exactly, so I find that possibility an important help and try not to forget updating it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a lot of work to find out which paper in arXiv has actually the same content as a published paper. However, taking arXiv's journal-ref field as a surrogate indicating which paper has a journal version out, I arrive at these fraction of papers: 
[image: fraction of arXiv papers with set "journal-ref" field]

So it looks as if the gut feeling that this is field-dependent is true: high energy and nuclear physics have consistently high fractions of papers with journal-ref field set. On the other hand, this seems far less common for maths papers.  Note that a certain drop at the end is to be expected as the preprints may be uploaded to arXiv considerably before the paper is accepted, printed and the journal-ref is updated in arXiv.

Here's the marginal plot over all fields:
[image: fraction of arXiv papers with journal-ref set] 
So overall, about 45% of the papers have a journal-ref. However, it is set for almost 60% of the 2001 - 2007 papers. Whether this is a real decline or just the lag between preprint and paper publishing remains to be seen (in a few years).

Also, neither the overall nor the subject-dependent trends seem to have a convincing increasing trend, even if the decline due to "not yet published and updated" is assumed to be the sole cause of the decreases.

For the complete picture, here's the development of total number of papers:
[image: number of papers in arXiv]

and number of papers with journal-ref set:
[image: number of arXiv papers with journal-ref set]

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to process the data and generate these graphs.

Comment: I guess the drop at the end is in fact mostly the publication delay. This is also field dependent - math journals are known for extraordinary publication delays, and that is very apparent in your plots.

Comment: @silvado: yes I agree. However, I wasn't aware that a delay of 6 years sounds reasonable e.g. for maths. In my field (chemistry/chemometrics) the delay is *much* shorter, also because we have to be careful whether pre-prints are considered previous publication, so I put my preprints to arXiv only after submission or even after acceptance/end of the embargo time. That makes much shorter to no delay.

Comment: @silvado: It certainly seems update delay, rather than publication delay.

Comment: By cutting off the 6 years, there is a clear downtrend for math/math-ph/astro-ph, and stay the same and up for others. It should be due to the difficult of publishing in those journal. To get the better comparison, we must also parse for real published paper and compare the date, which is very hard to do.

Comment: @cbeleites The tendency in maths to publish preprints very early certainly adds to the observed delay time in your data.

Comment: I post my papers on astro-ph after acceptance. None of my papers have journal-ref set, as far as I can see.

Comment: @xioxox: May I ask whether you have a particular reason for not setting `journal-ref`? I use it because I prefer "proper" citations and do not want to put any obstacles to people who wonder whether and to what extent the paper on arXiv and the journal version are the same. In fact, I put a box into the arXiv version stating that they are equivalent.

Comment: @cbeleites: I don't have the reference when I put it on after acceptance. No one in astronomy/astrophysics bothers adding it later. I think this likely because we all search for papers with ADS (http://adswww.harvard.edu/), which automatically associates the journal and astro-ph articles, giving the journal article by default.

Comment: @cbeleites you should also put a box in the _published_ version stating they are the same!

Comment: @DavidRoberts: nice idea, but in my field not feasible: we often have an embargo of a year before we're allowed to make the author's accepted manuscript publicly available.

Comment: Only *after* you sign a legal document ;-). You can always point to the arXiv as being a preprint version, then update that later to the final version.

Comment: Sorry but I have a dumb question: is it clear that all that's on arxiv eventually gets published?  The amount of crappy postings on arxiv is monotonically increasing in time, so the data could simply indicate a lack of selectivity at the level of peer-reviewed publications.