# How to find published article from arxiv preprint

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint

I just came from [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/128516/how-to-find-original-conference-of-the-paper-on-arxiv) and have a related but different question. My question is, is there an online tool that will allow me to definitively check if a **published** version of a preprint exists and locate the published version?

Take, for example, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00101) paper. Perhaps it was never published in a journal. But is there a way to definitively know?

Comment: Why would you like to know this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, this is impossible to determine *definitively* because there is no complete list of publications.

The correct solution is for the author to update their ArXiv submission with a citation.

The practical solution is to use Google Scholar to search for an article with the same text.

You can also ask the author, who will know if there is an *authorized* publication.