# Is it ok to submit a paper to arXiv after copyright transfer?

Tags: copyright, arxiv

I have a paper that was accepted and is already in press (you can download a PDF online), and I have already filled out the copyright transfer.

The publisher allows uploading preprint versions (including revisions after reviewer comments) to repositories such as arXiv, but is it ok to do so at this stage?

Comment: The copyright transfer, publishing agreement, or other publisher policies probably address this issue, at least implicitly.  What exactly do they say about uploading papers to the arXiv?  It's probably fine - it would be weird if they were fine with uploading your version before publication but not afterwards - but the only way to know for sure is to check what you agreed to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *The publisher allows uploading preprint versions (including revisions after reviewer comments)*

If you're allowed to do it, you are allowed to do it. **To be 100% sure, check the text of the copyright transfer agreement**, where these policies are spelt out. Or, if you don't like reading legal text so much, **it is summarized for many publishers in a nice color code at [SHERPA/Romeo](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo.php)**.

Comment: I think this is the right mindset... nothing in the copyright information specifies before or after publication (or in press).

Comment: I wouldn't trust Sherpa/Romeo for a decision. It is a good service to get an overview of journals, but I know that there has been error in there (some Wiley journals being listed as preprint friendy (yellow) when they are not). Before posting you should check with the editor or the copyright transfer agreement.

Answer (score 10):

This is a situation where you have to read what the copyright transfer agreement the journal had you sign (physically or digitally). That document is part of your publication contract so it is what you officially agreed to.

The last time I read one was, I think, an AIP journal and it had a paragraph on pre-print servers in general and arXiv in particular stating exactly which version of the paper was permissible to post. The language was "the author retains the rights to post [such and such version]..." so I could have posted that paper to arXiv after publication legally.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your legislation and the exact circumstances (funding sources), you may have retained certain rights for secondary publication regardless of what the copyright transfer says.

This is the case e.g. in [Germany](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/11226/725).

So in addition to the copyright transfer, check your local copyright law.